# Efetuar a extração dos argumentos de uma URL com Erlang

Tags: erlang

Preciso de uma grande ajuda em Erlang, pois sou iniciante na linguagem. Estou fazendo um trabalho com alguns amigos que consiste no desenvolvimento de um barramento orientado a serviço, permitindo manipular várias requisições.
Estou em busca de uma solução de como será tratada a URL oriunda do cliente do barramento quanto à extração de argumentos.

Os parametros podem ser da URL **( URL/parametro1/parametro2 )** ou do tipo Query URL?`param=value&param1=value1`

Se alguém tiver algum código exemplo de como poderia ser feito ficarei grato.
Para uma melhor visualização do problema o código do barramento que está sendo construído encontra-se no GITHUB no link:

https://github.com/PPCA2014/ppca_soa/

Grato desde Já

Answer (score 0):

O módulo [`http_uri`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/http_uri.html) possui uma função `parse` capaz de interpretar uma URL. Chamando-a com as opções padrão:

```
parse("http://example.com:8080/path/to/resource?q1=foo&q2=bar#fragmento")
```

Resultado:

```
{http,[],"example.com",8080,"/path/to/resource","?q1=foo&q2=bar#fragmento"}
```

[Exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/L1q3sd). Há algumas opções para customizar a interpretação da URL (veja a documentação de `parse/2`), mas não entendi muito bem como usá-las (também sou iniciante em Erlang).